# My Excel row is locked at height of 409.5 and I want to increase the size

Tags: excel, formatting, height, row

The height for one of my rows in excel maxes out at 409.5 and I need to increase the height. Where/how can I fix this.

Comment: For whatever reason, it appears 409 is the max for MS Excel.  You can't break it up into more rows?  (This might be an indication that Excel is not the right tool for your particular job).

Comment: I have the same need.

Answer (score 28):

1. Create a row below the row you want taller than 409.5
2. Select cell of top row, and cell of bottom row
3. Click arrow next to the **Merge & Center** button in the **Alignment** section of the **Home** tab on the ribbon
4. Click **Merge Cells**

You can repeat this process multiple times if two cells worth of height isn't enough.

Note that **Merge & Centre** isn't available for a table, only a standard worksheet.

Comment: Small note: AutoFit option won't work properly for merged cells.
[Microsoft support](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/you-cannot-use-the-autofit-feature-for-rows-or-columns-that-contain-merged-cells-in-excel-34b54dd7-9bfc-6c8f-5ee3-2715d7db4353).

Comment: Good workaround given there's no alternative.

Comment: pretty neat, thank you. `[+1]`

Comment: Thats just stupid. Why dont they just allow "infinite" cell height *facepalm*

Answer (score 5):

You can merge two rows so that you get more space to work.

Comment: Could you please elaborate?